# Can Java Streams transform a list of points into a list of their coordinates?

Tags: java, mapping, java-stream, variable-expansion

I have a stream of Point3Ds in a JavaFX 8 program. I would like, for the sake of creating a Mesh from them, to be able to produce a list of their (x, y, z) coordinates instead.

This is a simple enough task through traditional Java looping. (Almost trivial, actually.) However, in the future, I'll likely be dealing with tens of thousands of points; and I would very much like to be able to use the Java Stream API and accomplish this with a parallel stream.

I suppose what I'm looking for is the rough equivalent of this psuedocode:

```
List<Double> coordinates = stream.parallel().map(s -> (s.getX(), s.getY(), s.getZ())).collect(Collectors.asList());
```

As of yet, I've found no such feature though. Could someone kindly give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: Are you saying you want an undifferentiated `List<Double>` containing `{x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,x3,y3,z3,...,xn,yn,zn}`?

Comment: Yes, an undifferentiated list is a good way of putting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` :

```
List<Double> coordinates = 
    stream.parallel()
          .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.getX(), s.getY(), s.getZ()))
          .collect(Collectors.asList());
```

Comment: Very nice. +1. However, although this perfectly answers the question of how to do this, it actually misses the implicit goal of improving performance by using parallel streams. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35047191/5221149) for why.

Answer (score 0):

Why? Even with "tens of thousands of points", the code will complete in very little time, and you won't really gain anything "with a parallel stream".

This sounds like a perfect example of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize), where you potentially complicate the code for something that isn't (yet) a problem, and is unlikely to ever be one, in this case at least.

To prove my point, I created the test code below.

To minimize the effect of GC runs, I ran this code with `-Xms10g -Xmx10g`, and added the explicit `gc()` calls, so test runs were running with a "clean slate".

As always, performance testing is subject to JIT optimizations and other factors, so a warm-up loop was provided.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    List<Point3D> input = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++)
        input.add(new Point3D(rnd.nextDouble(), rnd.nextDouble(), rnd.nextDouble()));

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        test1(input);
        test2(input);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        long start1 = System.nanoTime();
        test1(input);
        long end1 = System.nanoTime();
        System.gc();
        long start2 = System.nanoTime();
        test2(input);
        long end2 = System.nanoTime();
        System.gc();
        System.out.printf("%.6f  %.6f%n", (end1 - start1) / 1_000_000d, (end2 - start2) / 1_000_000d);
    }
}
private static List<Double> test1(List<Point3D> input) {
    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Point3D point : input) {
        list.add(point.getX());
        list.add(point.getY());
        list.add(point.getZ());
    }
    return list;
}
private static List<Double> test2(List<Point3D> input) {
    return input.stream().parallel()
                         .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.getX(), s.getY(), s.getZ()))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

*RESULT*

```
0.355267  0.392904
0.205576  0.260035
0.193601  0.232378
0.194740  0.290544
0.193601  0.238365
0.243497  0.276286
0.200728  0.243212
0.197022  0.240646
0.192175  0.239790
0.198162  0.279708
```

No major difference, although parallel stream seems slightly slower.
Also notice that it completes in **less than 0.3 ms**, for 10,000 points.
It's nothing!

Let's try to increase the count from 10,000 to 10,000,000 (skipping warmup):

```
433.716847  972.100743
260.662700  693.263850
250.699271  736.744653
250.486281  813.615375
249.722716  714.296997
254.704145  796.566859
254.713840  829.755767
253.368331  959.365322
255.016928  973.306254
256.072177  1047.562090
```

Now there's a definite degradation of the parallel stream. It is **3 times slower**. This is likely caused by extra GC runs.

**CONCLUSION: Premature optimization is bad!!!!**

In your case, you actually made it worse.

Comment: In a sense; but I might counter that the other realm of programming is the human element. A single line that runs functional processing is often much easier for programmers, later down the line, to understand than a seven or eight-line block, particularly when the sacrifice is only making it slightly slower. (The journalist's rule.) Additionally, as you pointed out, GC can be tuned. All the same, I do appreciate your note that in this instance it's actually making the processing slightly slower. My usage will involve OpenCL at a later phase, and I imagine the buffering will eclipse this.

Comment: I've noted this in a comment in my code; in case it becomes an issue later.

Comment: @MichaelEricOberlin Sure, if your reason is simpler code, but then what was the point of the *"I'll likely be dealing with tens of thousands of points"* part of your question, or the *"accomplish this with a parallel stream"* followup? It made it seem that your main reason for doing this was to gain performance thought the use of parallel streams, and it is that thinking I was addressing. If all you wanted was simpler code, your question should simply have been "How do I do this with streams?"

Comment: All right, perhaps a clearer expression of my concern is that it seemed as though it should be possible to perform such a Stream mapping; and I am inclined to use newer APIs when I can. They exist because Java 6 is no longer optimal for modern hardware, just because it will technically run. This implies a fault in my understanding, which is where Stack Overflow comes in.

Comment: @MichaelEricOberlin Parallel processing is great for improving scalability of heavy/slow tasks, but your example is very far from heavy, and you're collecting the result in a list, so it still has to serialize everything at the end, creating a single-threaded bottleneck. Use new features *where appropriate*, and the use of streams to make the code simpler is good, here, but the use parallel processing is not. Just because a feature is new doesn't make it better at everything.